# get the index of a button in a x:Array of a ListBox (wpf)

Tags: wpf, arrays, button, listbox, indexing

Hello
Is there a way to get the index of a button in an x:Array of a ListBox.

I know that I can get the button info once clicked (via the sender argument) but I can't get its index.

ListBox.CurrentItem and ListBox.SelectedItem don't work

no luck with
int t = this.lstButtons.SelectedIndex;

t=this.lstButtons.Items.CurrentPosition;

t=lstButtons.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer((Button)sender);

```
            <x:Array Type="Button" >

                <Button Content="Button1"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Click="Button_Click" />
                <Button Content="Button2"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <Button Content="Button3" BorderThickness="4"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </x:Array>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
```

Comment: Thank you for your pointer var bouts = lstButtons.ItemsSource.Cast<Button>().ToArray<Button>(); int index = Array.IndexOf(bouts, ((Button)sender));

Answer (score 0):

Well I would re-think the problem because it sounds like a pretty brittle and roundabout way to take conditional action based on the item. But what you could probably do is:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf((Button[])listBox.ItemsSource, clickedButton);
```

Comment: Thank you for your pointer var bouts = lstButtons.ItemsSource.Cast<Button>().ToArray<Button>(); int index = Array.IndexOf(bouts, ((Button)sender));